# Eliminate Multiple Output Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I'm running this query to test my function

```
select first_name, last_name,get_balance_due(orders.order_id) 
from customers, orders, order_lines 
Where customers.customer_id=orders.customer_id and orders.order_id = order_lines.order_id and
 order_date >= to_date( '30-Nov-1999', 'DD-Mon-YYYY' )
   AND order_date<  to_date( '01-Dec-1999', 'DD-Mon-YYYY' );
Group By First_name, Last_name, get_balance_due(orders.order_id)
```

The output is repeated 3 times.

```
FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME  GET_BALANCE_DUE(ORDERS.ORDER_ID)  
Jan  Busse  602450.56  
Jan  Busse  602450.56  
Jan  Busse  602450.56
```

The function get_balance_due

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_balance_due
(order_id_f NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
AS 
balance_due_f NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(total_amount) INTO balance_due_f
FROM order_lines
WHERE order_id_f = order_id
RETURN balance_due_f;
end;
```

How can I have 1 result instead of 3?

Comment: I assume that this order has three rows in the `order_lines` table.  Why are you joining to the `order_lines` table in the first place?  It doesn't appear that this is doing anything useful and is just causing additional rows to be returned.  Your `GROUP BY` also doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: You can use distinct clause in your query to avoid such situations.

Comment: @JustinCave yes this order has three rows, I will modify my statement and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the order_lines from your select statement:

```
select first_name, last_name,get_balance_due(orders.order_id) 
from customers INNER JOIN orders
ON customers.customer_id=orders.customer_id
Where  
 order_date >= to_date( '30-Nov-1999', 'DD-Mon-YYYY' )
   AND order_date<  to_date( '01-Dec-1999', 'DD-Mon-YYYY' );
```

(and use INNER JOINs)